# get equation of intersection of two surfaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry

For quite some applications it is useful to get the equation of the intersection of two surfaces. Now I mostly try to "guess" it, look at how the surfaces are and then solve for a certain value.

However it would really help to have a generic approach for this. As surfaces can be described by a parametrization $S = r(u,v)$, or by simple equations for x, y & z there are three cases I can see:

1. Two surfaces defined by parameter equations ($r(u,v) = p(u,v)$)
2. Two surfaces defined by coordinates ($S_1(x,y,z)=S_2(x,y,z)$)
3. A surface defined by parameters as well as one by coordinates: ($r(u,v) = S_2(x,y,z)$)

Though on a second thought I'm wondering if there really can be a good definition of a surface with coordinates. Mostly it is described as "the plane with eq....." or "the sphere with eq.....". So I guess the very first step is to always parametrize it?

Also can this method be extended to describe the surface of generic volumes?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to integrate over a surface, for example, you pretty much need to parametrize it (or large portions of it). However, in general, it's quite impossible to explicitly parametrize a surface. For example, consider the surface given by the equation 
$$f(x,y,z)=(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2-10(x^2+y^2)+6z^2=0\,.$$
It's not hard to check this is a smooth surface. But what *is* it? To parametrize it in a useful way you must first manipulate the algebra to get something more informative.

So far as your original question is concerned, generally you'll have the best luck, I bet, with version 3. But here's a fun curve to parametrize: the intersection of the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=4$ and the cylinder $(x-1)^2+y^2=1$.